# How to write array properly in CSV file?

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to write an array into excel files. I used for loop to generate the array. When I print the array it gives me 98 records but in excel files its write 90 results. If array has 150 results then it also write 90 results. Here is my code.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    ob_start();
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
    ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
    include_once('classes/html_dom.php');

    if ($_GET['q']) {
        $mobile = $_GET['q'];
    }
    $filename = ucfirst($mobile);

    for($i=1; $i<=4;$i++) {

        //$target_url = 'https://www.awok.com/mobile-phones/ds-582/?brand='.$mobile.'&set-filter=Y&PAGEN_1='.$i.'';

        $target_url = 'Source-Files/Awok-'.$filename.'-Mobile-'.$i.'.html';

        $html = new simple_html_dom();

        $html->load_file($target_url); 

        $SiteUrl = 'https://www.awok.com';

        $products       = array();

        foreach($html->find('div.subcat_cat_item_text a ') as $link_1) {

                foreach($link_1->find('p.subcat_cat_item_title') as $link_2) {
                    foreach($link_1->find('span.subcat_cat_item_newprice') as $link_3) {
                        array_push($products, array("Mobile Name" => $link_2->plaintext , "Link" => $SiteUrl.$link_1->href , "Price" => $link_3->plaintext));

                    }

                }

            } 
        /*echo '<pre>'; print_r($products); echo '</pre>';*/

            $output = fopen("php://output",'w') or die("Can't open php://output");
            header("Content-Type:application/csv"); 
            header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=Awok ".$filename." Mobile List.csv"); 
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

                foreach($products as $product) {
                    fputcsv($output, $product);
                }
                fclose($output) or die("Can't close php://output");     
        ob_flush();
    }
?>
```

Comment: open the file in a plane text editor, check for errors

Comment: There is no error. If print_r gives proper result then why it is not written properly in csv file??

Comment: Any help for this problem??

Comment: no idea what seeing the specific array.

Comment: If I send u the files then can u check it??